# Do I use getfield or load when defining the body of a member function in Java (MicroJava)?

Tags: java, bytecode

edit: This question relates to MicroJava bytecode, rather than actual Java bytecode

---

bytecode question - consider the following:

```
class C {
    int d;
    int m() {
        return d;
    }
}
```

when defining the body of function m(), it should look something like this:

```
enter 0, 0
getfield 0
exit
return
```

now, the `getfield` instruction requires that the address of the object be on top of the stack, however, in this case, it is not (at least i think it isn't, as i haven't explicitly put it there, and don't know how to either, seeing as i'm in the class itself).

on the other hand, the `load` instruction would be relative to the function itself, and since i haven't passed any parameters to function, that seems to be out of the question.

also, since `class C` is defined within another class, i.e. program, using `getstatic` should also be wrong, as it's not a global variable.

any ideas?

Comment: On my platform it look like `aload_0` `getfield #2` `ireturn`.

Comment: don't just guess the byte code. Run `javap -c` command to actually see it.

Comment: oh well now i'm just confused, isn't `aload` used for arrays?! also, this isn't pure java, it's actually MicroJava, a language we have to implement for our compilers course.

Comment: In normal Java, `aload` is for object. (Recall that arrays are also objects.)

Comment: urgh, i was just gonna say (assume) that but i can only edit the post after 5 mins. in any case, this doesn't really help me all that much, since in MicroJava, aload is specifically for arrays, hence my confusion. thanks anyway!

Comment: You should edit the question to make it more clear that you're not using real Java. The code you posted bears no relation to Java bytecode, and not knowing MicroJava, I can't really help you.